# Matar hilo en ejecucion Android

Tags: android, hilos

Tengo este metodo donde al pulsar el boton de retroceder del movil mata un hilo que esta en ejecucion en la actividad de la que se quiere retroceder.

Clase que llama he inicializa el hilo:

```
//Declaras una variable tipo Thread
public Thread HiloConsumo;

// Se crea el hilo
HiloConsumo = new HiloConsumidor("INTC")                
HiloConsumo.setName("HiloConsumidor");
HiloConsumo.start();

// Metodo que al pulsar el boton de retroceder vuelve al Main y mata el HiloConsumidor
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (HiloConsumo != null)//valida si existe instancia de Thread.
    {
        HiloConsumo.interrupt();  //Interrumpe su ejecución.
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

HiloConsumidor:

```
public class HiloConsumidor extends Thread {

String codigo;

public HiloConsumidor(String codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    Stock stock = null;

    while (!HiloConsumo.isInterrupted()) {
        try {
            stock = YahooFinance.get(codigo);

            Thread.sleep(10000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            this.interrupt();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Pero al salir y regresar a la actividad anterior, que es el main el hilo sigue realizando una serie de peticiones a una API sin detenerse. Dentro del hilo tengo un blucle infinito lo comento pero creo que se deba a eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas un bucle `while` dentro del `thread` pasa como condición el método `isInterrupted()`, este comprobara si has interrumpido el thread para detener la ejecución.

```
HiloConsumo = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!HiloConsumo.isInterrupted()) {
                //Tu codigo
            }
        }
    };
HiloConsumo.start();
```

EDITO:

Basandome en el nuevo código que proporcionas basta con usas `this`en lugar de `HiloConsumo` ya que la propia clase (referenciada como this) se extiende de `thread`. Tambien aconsejo que saques del `if` el `super.onBackPressed();` para que el botón "back" se ejecute correctamente si en algún momento no inicias el thread.

Clase que llama he inicializa el hilo:

```
//Declaras una variable tipo Thread
 public Thread HiloConsumo;

// Se crea el hilo
 HiloConsumo = new HiloConsumidor("INTC");                
 HiloConsumo.setName("HiloConsumidor");
 HiloConsumo.start();

// Metodo que al pulsar el boton de retroceder vuelve al Main y mata el HiloConsumidor
 public void onBackPressed() {
    if (HiloConsumo != null)//valida si existe instancia de Thread.
    {
        HiloConsumo.interrupt();  //Interrumpe su ejecución.
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

HiloConsumidor:

```
public class HiloConsumidor extends Thread {

 String codigo;

 public HiloConsumidor(String codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

@Override
 public void run() {

    Stock stock = null;

    while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
        try {
            stock = YahooFinance.get(codigo);

            Thread.sleep(10000);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            this.interrupt();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: He cambiado la condición del while que era true a !HiloConsumidor.isInterrupted() y me da este pequeño fallo: **Non-static method 'isInterrupted' cannot be referenced from a static context** sabes a qué podría deberse?

Comment: Lo llamas desde un metodo ? revisa si es static o no, y la declaración del Thread tambien

Comment: lo llamo desde el onCreate de un una activity, actualize la pregunta del post

Comment: Respuesta editada con la solución.

Comment: funciono a la perfección ;D

Comment: genial, cualquier duda que surja es bien recibida.